Electron JS - Methods from the preload library do not work
I have my own desktop application, it should launch a Minecraft bot for a local server. In my preload.js I add mineflayer (library)
Thus
const { contextBridge } = require("electron");
const mineflayers = require("mineflayer");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('libs', {
    mineflayer: mineflayers,
});

In main.js
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = require('electron');

let win;

function createWindow() {
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        resizable: false,
        width: 900,
        height: 700,
        autoHideMenuBar: true,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    });

    win.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, './html/index.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    }));

    win.webContents.openDevTools();

    win.on('closed', () => {
        win = null;
    });
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    app.quit();
});

When I try to connect the bot to the server it fails. As soon as I try to use any mentod like bot.chat("message")
I'm getting the error chat is not a function
$(".connect-button").click(() => {
    let date = new Date()

    $(".console-log").append(`<br>[${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}:${date.getSeconds()}] Запуск...`);
    const client = libs.mineflayer.createBot({
        username: "testBot",
        host: "ip",
        port: "port",
        versions: "1.16.5"
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
        client.chat("10 sec");
    }, 10000);
});

How do I use the library's functions?
I tried to use sandbox but realized that it was removed in version 1.20
I also tried adding the chat method directly to the bot’s connect function - similar
    const client = libs.mineflayer.createBot({
        username: "testBot",
        host: "ip",
        port: "port",
        versions: "1.16.5"
    }).on("messagestr", msg => {console.log(msg)});

